# Override Sails.js Waterline intercept Find method

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have a model named Product.
I want configurable across the board filtering for this model.

For example: `sails.config.field = 2;`

When I do GET /Product I want it to essentially do GET /Product?where={"field": 2}

The above works for blueprint by adding a policy, but I want consistent behavior when I use the waterline ORM

**GET /Product 
and Product.find() should return the same thing.**

I can override the model: Product.find and it would work perfectly... IF there was some way for me to access the underlying find code.

The code I am using to intercept the blueprint is:

```
if (!req.query.where) {
    req.query.where = `{"status":{">":0,">=":${sails.config.catalogVersions.status}}}`;
  } else {
    const parsedWhere = JSON.parse(req.query.where);
    parsedWhere.status = {
      '>': 0,
      '>=': sails.config.catalogVersions.status,
    };
    req.query.where = JSON.stringify(parsedWhere);
  }
```

I could very easily apply this to a Model.find interceptor.

**Is there any way that once sails is loaded, I can access the root find method on a model even if its been overwritten at load time?**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could think on something like this one:

https://github.com/muhammadghazali/sails-hook-pagination

It's a hook and maybe works for your intended use.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the hook:orm:loaded hook, to run some code which monkeypatched all of the models with a defaultScope which was stored in each of my models. It works well as I can easily modify the default criteria on all of the models and get consistent behavior across blueprint and waterline.

For code see:
[Is there a way to override sails.js waterline endpoint with custom controller, but keep built in pagination, and filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62395812/is-there-a-way-to-override-sails-js-waterline-endpoint-with-custom-controller-b/62583347#62583347)